# how to check which element of the Listview is in the view in react native

Tags: listview, react-native

I want to implement the same feature as that of Facebook , that Video gets played as soon as it comes into the view.

Similarly, I want to check that which `Row` of the `ListView`  is in the view at the present moment .

Answer (score 1):

The `onChangeVisibleRows` prop will let you know when a row goes visible or invisible: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.37/docs/listview.html#onchangevisiblerows.